# Issue with TensorFlow Model Training: Loss Function Convergence Problem

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working on training a neural network using TensorFlow for a classification task, and I've encountered a challenge related to the convergence of the loss function. I've implemented a simple model architecture, loaded my dataset, and configured the optimizer, but the loss seems to fluctuate without converging.

- I have preprocessed my data and ensured it's in the correct format.
- Created a neural network model using TensorFlow's Keras API.
- Configured the appropriate loss function, optimizer, and metrics.
- Adjusted the learning rate to see if it affects convergence.

Comment: There seems to be no programming questions here...

Comment: Without knowing the purpose, the architecture, the optimizer etc. it will be very difficult to give an informed answer to this question.